# DHCP Client automatic Adressleasing

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-server, dhcp

Hello Stackoverflow Community i just wanted to ask if a DCHP leasetime is up while the DHCP Client pc isn't turned on how can i let him lease a new ip address without manually deactivating and re-activate the network interface? i know that if the lease time is up while the PC is off he can still authenticate himself at the domain due to the APIPA address but from there on i have no idea how to ask for a new ip address without doing it manually.the first idea i had was maybe a script that applies to all computers in the OU ? would it work if the script would just do "ipconfig /release" followed by "ipconfig /renew" ? because i tried this in the cmd but it didn't worked.Or could i just write a script which deactivates the network interface and start it again so the user don't have to do it manually ?

Comment: Windows should renew the lease or obtain a new lease automatically as soon as the PC starts up.  You don't need to do anything.  If this isn't working, there might be a problem with your DHCP server.

Comment: Ok i figured out that only one client doesn't get an ip address.Sometimes this one client can't authenticate at the domain only when i log in as an administrator.